# Understanding IF-statement

Tags: php, excel

I kind of understand the basics of what it does, but it gets confusing. If anyone could re-write it into simple pseudo code, it would be greatly appreciated!

I'm writing a PHP application and I need the same algorithm in PHP, but it's not working.

```
=IF(CC_stolpar=2;
    IF(Antal_slanor<4;
       6*Antal_dubbelgrind;
       Antal_dubbelgrind*Antal_slanor*2)
    +
    IF(Antal_slanor<4;
       3*Antal_enkelgrind;
       Antal_enkelgrind*Antal_slanor);
    0)
```

Comment: hint: read like that IF(condition;then;else)

Comment: Thanks PW. And thanks beth for the editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why he's testing for `antal_slanor<4` twice, it should be equivalent to

```
=IF(CC_stolpar=2;
    IF(Antal_slanor<4;
       6*Antal_dubbelgrind              + 3*Antal_enkelgrind;
       Antal_dubbelgrind*Antal_slanor*2 + Antal_enkelgrind*Antal_slanor);
    0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nested IF statements, which follow the pattern     `IF-THEN-ELSE`

```
IF (condition); what to do if condition is true; what to do if condition is false
```

So your outer IF is `IF(CC_stolpar=2 THEN (do all this complicated stuff) ELSE 0`.

That's pretty simple. Either `CC_stolpar` is 2 or it isn't, and if it has any other value than 2, then the result is zero.

That "complicated stuff" is summing the results of two different IF statements.

The first one is

```
IF(Antal_slanor<4;
6*Antal_dubbelgrind;
Antal_dubbelgrind*Antal_slanor*2)
```

If `Antal_slanor` is less than 4, then multiply `Antal_dubbelgrind` times 6.

If `Antal_slanor` is greater than or equal to 4, then multiply `Antal_dubbelgrind` times `Antal_slanor` times 2.

You will only get one result from this, based on whether `Antal_slanor` is less than 4 or not.

You repeat essentially the same process for the other IF, and sum the results.

```
IF(Antal_slanor<4;
3*Antal_enkelgrind;
Antal_enkelgrind*Antal_slanor);
```

Both of these nested IF statements are evaluating whether `Antal_slanor` is less than 4. So, you could merge them into a single IF if that makes sense to you.

In the end, I would suggest for your own sanity and the sanity of others who may have to read this after you, keep the formula as simple as possible in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look at the pieces rather than in a line.

As a hint, it CC_stolar=2, then the result is the sum of two nested IF statements.

Perhaps some brackets would help:

```
=IF(CC_stolpar=2;
    {
    IF(Antal_slanor<4;
        {
            6*Antal_dubbelgrind;
        } else {
            Antal_dubbelgrind*Antal_slanor*2)
        }
    +IF(Antal_slanor<4;
        {
            3*Antal_enkelgrind;
        } else {
            Antal_enkelgrind*Antal_slanor)
        }
    } else {
        ;0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF CC_poles == 2 then 
    IF NUMBER_OF_POLES < 4 THEN
         RESULT = 6*NUMBER_OF_DOUBLE_GATES + 3* NUMBER_OF_SINGLE_GATES;
      ELSE
         RESULT= NUMBER_OF_DOUBLE_GATES*NUMBER_OF_POLES*2 + NUMBER_OF_SINGLE_GATES *
                 NUMBER_OF_POLES
    ENDIF
ELSE
    RESULT = 0
ENDIF
```